# Alternative to stopping SQL queries on Redshift when AJAX request is aborted

Tags: java, ajax, amazon-redshift, database-performance

We have a lot of filters(vehicle year, model, make, driver name etc). Every selected filter will generate 5-10 SQL queries, which are executing between time range 5-15 seconds. Let's say that our users mark filters very fast: selected some driver, next some vehicle, some data range etc. Within 15 seconds a user can send several dozen AJAX request, which reaches to the server and run SQL queries, the database is clogging, gets more and more queries and each execution takes longer.

We thought about the solution which will stop query when AJAX request is aborted, but this is not an easy solution. Is there better and easier solution than stopping queries when AJAX request is aborted?

We use Redshift for analytics data and PostgreSQL for user data etc.
We have high-level cache, which caches the results. Redshift has 16
nodes of dc2.large instances, we have also set 15 concurrent queries
on WLM configuration(queries don't queue up). We have encoding for all
tables, sortkeys and distkeys. We have a several dozen tables, but one
big with all transactions which have about 300M records and ~70
columns.
In AWS console on Redshift Performance tab, we can see that leader node works for 99-100% and other nodes about 10-30% during heavy load.

Comment: You need to optimise your redshift cluster & your method of querying it. I think that question is out of scope for stackoverflow as it will require detailed analysis and perhaps a week work with a competent and experienced redshift expert. When you say "Every selected filter will generate 5-10 SQL queries, which are executing between time range 5-15 seconds", that indicates to me that you may have approached redshift the wrong way altogether. if you would like to elaborate on those queries, what do they look like, how much data in the tables etc, we may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks you. I have just edited post and added more information.

Comment: opax, please can you show an example of the query that takes so long? together with how long it takes?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, redshift is not meant for transactional DB its an analytical DB. Secondly, if there is a huge number of queries you should consider grouping the queries or caching the result. Also, consider using [work load management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_workload_mngmt_classification.html).

Comming back to the original problem you will have to figure out the queries which were started by the timed out AJAX call. For which you will have to rely on `svv_transactions` and `stv_recents` these tables will return you the processes and queries that are being run. Next, you will have to [PG_CANCEL_BACKEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_CANCEL_BACKEND.html) to cancel the query or in worst case use [PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND.html) to terminate the process that is being run. Although there is no easy way to automate this if you happen to automate it do share your experience .

Comment: this is not an answer, should be a comment